# What is the importance of jboss.bind.address

Tags: unix, jboss

What is the importance of jboss.bind.address? What if we bind to wrong address?

Can you explain me the meaning of this command:

```
nohup ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/run.sh -Djboss.bind.address=${BIND_IP} >> ${JBOSS_LOG} &
```

Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It tells JBoss which **local** address to bind to. The server will only listen on that specific interface, not on all local interfaces.

(e.g. if you have bind address set to `127.0.0.1`, it will not listen to connection from other hosts, only on localhost.)

That command line just starts JBoss in the background and sends to output to `$JBOSS_LOG`.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. My Jboss running on '150.30.32.55', but my jboss bind address pointed to '150.30.32.54'. Then what is the effect? We are not seeing any difference, only log files are not rolling up. How it related?

Comment: use `netstat` to see what real addresses/ports it's listening on. if the bind address you specified is not one of the servers real IP addresses, I have no idea what happens.